# Gestures in Android

Tags: android, imageview, gestures

There are more than 30 pictures in my android app.. I'm planning to show one image at a time when the user swipes left or right.

What is the best way to do this? Can you please point some working examples?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Gallery . Here is the link - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

And

http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/android-gallery-widget-example-and-tutorial/

Comment: @ Naveen : Yes . I am sorry i missed out on the deprecation part. You  can probably try using an Horizontal scroll view -http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    see this ...
    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html
You can use Gesture Detector class so detect left,rigth,up down swipes
```